# Changing what function to call depending on which button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay So I what to have 3 buttons

```
<div id="button1" onclick="choose1()">Button1</div>
<div id="button2" onclick="choose2()">Button2</div>
<div id="button3" onclick="choose3()">Button3</div>
```

And a start button

```
<div id="startButton" onclick="noFunction()">Start</div>
```

I want to make it so that pressing on of the 3 option buttons it changes what function will be called from the start button and the background image of the start button should change.

Is there a way to do this with just javascript or do I need jquery? 
It also doesn't seem possible to use onclick on div tags, jquery to do that aswell?

Comment: You can use `onclick` on `<div>` tags. But you *shouldn't* use `onclick` on *any* tags. Don't confuse your HTML layout and display with your JavaScript functionality. Bind your click handlers directly in the JS code.

Comment: @nbrooks That seems Like a really smart thing to do, how would I go about doing it?

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mWutg/), linked in my answer below, which shows how you can bind click handlers to elements from your JS code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/mWutg/1/)

You can use `onclick` on `<div>` tags. But you *shouldn't* use `onclick` on *any* tags. Don't confuse your HTML layout and display with your JavaScript functionality. Bind your click handlers directly in the JS code (note that this solution is using jQuery):

HTML:

```
<div id="button1">Button1</div>
<div id="button2">Button2</div>
<div id="button3">Button3</div>

<div id="startButton">Start</div>
```

JS:

```
function choose1() {
    // ...
}
function choose2() {
    // ...   
}
function choose3() {
    // ...  
}
$(function() {
    $("#button1").click(choose1);
    $("#button2").click(choose2);
    $("#button3").click(choose3);    
});
```

Comment: Note that this example is just changing the background color for simplicity, but the same approach can be adopted for modifying a background image. In that case, you would use the [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) css property, rather than the background-color property which I am using.

Comment: Thank you so much for this anwser, I'd  just upvote you but I can't yet. So thanks :D

Comment: Sorry I got a follow up question if I now also have $("#startButton").click(noOption); How do I change that since it's not relevant to the div I can't document.getElementById("startButton").onclick = startOption1;

Comment: @Pants Sure that's possible--see [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/mWutg/3/). In your `choose1`, `choose2`, and `choose3` functions, you simply need to bind the appropriate function to the start button by saying `$("#startButton").off('click').click(functionName)` or `document.getElementById("startButton").onclick = functionName;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in javascript (anything possible with jQuery is possible with plain javascript, since jQuery is written in javascript).

Changing the click handler for the startButton from javascript is very straightforward:

```
document.getElementById("startButton").onclick = newFunction;
```

Changing the background image is also pretty simple:

```
document.getElementById("startButton").style.backgroundImage = "image.png";
```

Obviously, you should replace newFunction and "image.png" with the function and image you actually want to use respectively.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery ***IS*** javascript. It is just a library of functions/methods that you can call.

To solve your problem, you should write a function that changes the `onclick` property of your start button, and add the function you write to the `onclick` of the other buttons.

Like so:

```
function chooseOne(){
    document.getElementById('startButton').onclick="/\*whatever\*/";
}
```

A technology like what @nbrooks said in the comments that would do this very well is [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org)

Answer (score 0):

You can say

```
function choose1() {
document.getElementById('startButton').onclick = function() {
 alert("Button one was originally press");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give each selector button a class, you can use javascript to interate them and bind a click event. Then you can store in a data property a key which you can lookup in a json object start stores the related action handler and image. Finally in your click handler you can pull these properties and apply them to the start button by setting the onClick handler and background image of the start button.

```
<div class="startSelector" data-startdataid="1">Button1</div>
<div class="startSelector" data-startdataid="2">Button2</div>
<div class="startSelector" data-startdataid="3">Button3</div>

<div id="startButton">Start</div>

<script>

  var startData = {
  "1": {
    action: function() {
      alert("Button 1 was selected");
    },
    image: "/images/button1.jpg"
  },"2": {
    action: function() {
      alert("Button 2 was selected");
    },
    image: "/images/button2.jpg"
  },"3": {
    action: function() {
      alert("Button 3 was selected");
    },
    image: "/images/button3.jpg"
  }
}


var changeStartButton = function(e) {
  var startDataIndex = e.target.dataset.startdataid
  var data = startData[startDataIndex]
  document.getElementById("startButton").onclick = data.action
  document.getElementById("startButton").style.backgroundImage = data.image
}

items =  document.getElementsByClassName("startSelector")
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  items[i].addEventListener("click", changeStartButton);
}
</script>
```

**Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/Xk8rv/3/